# SQL statement working in MySQL not working in Postgresql - Sum & group_by rails 3

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

So I'm very new to working in SQL in general, let alone rails but I have this statement that works in MySQL:

```
portfolio_values.select("portfolio_values.*, SUM(portfolio_values.value) as totals").group("portfolio_values.day").map(&:totals)
```

But in postgresql is throws this error:

> GError: ERROR:  column "portfolio_values.id" must appear in the GROUP
>   BY clause or be used in an aggregate function : SELECT
>   portfolio_values.*, SUM(portfolio_values.value) as totals FROM
>   "portfolio_values"  WHERE "portfolio_values"."user_id" = 3 GROUP BY
>   portfolio_values.day ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR: 
>   column "portfolio_values.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

I just don't really understand what its saying I should be doing differently?

Comment: The answer directly depends on the version or PostgreSQL in use - which I fail to gather from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add the `portfolio_values.id` column to the `GROUP BY` statement - like so:

```
portfolio_values.select("portfolio_values.*, SUM(portfolio_values.value) as totals").group("portfolio_values.id, portfolio_values.day").map(&:totals)
```

### EDIT

While this is valid SQL, it's not a useful query - see other post.

Comment: True that, I didn't really look at rest of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Since PostgreSQL **9.1** a primary key column  in the `GROUP BY` list covers the whole table. Therefore, given that `portfolio_values.id` is, in fact, the primary key, you can simplify:

```
portfolio_values.select("portfolio_values.*, SUM(portfolio_values.value) as totals").group("portfolio_values.id").map(&:totals)
```

I quote the [9.1 release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-1.html#AEN107670):

> Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the query target list when the primary
>   key is specified in the GROUP BY clause (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> The SQL standard allows this behavior, and because of the primary key,
>   the result is unambiguous.

---

**However**, in your case, this results in **nonsense either way**.

a. `portfolio_values.id` is the primary key.

Then `SUM(portfolio_values.value)` is pointless. There can only be one row per group.

b. `portfolio_values.id` is not the primary key.

Then you cannot include `portfolio_values.*` in the `SELECT` list.

---

If you wish to learn the meaning of `*` in a `SELECT`, [start by reading the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html).

Comment: I dont see how this could accomplish my goal, as its not grouping by day (which is a column in the table)

Comment: @Elliot: The point is, your goal is impossible. Selecting `portfolio_values.*` and `SUM(portfolio_values.value` at the the same time is logical nonsense. You cannot have the pudding and eat it, too.

Comment: I dont even know what portfolio_values.* does - I'm extremely new to SQL, I'm just trying to return the sum of values grouped by day. Which I accomplished like such: portfolio_values.select("portfolio_values.day, SUM(portfolio_values.value) as totals").group("portfolio_values.day")

Comment: @Elliot: Please *edit your question* and describe your goal there. An answer will be found. :) That new example makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want distinct on:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Specifically something like:

select distinct on (yourdatefield) field1, field2, field3 from sometable;