# Handling of generate_series() in queries with date or timestamp with / without time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timezone, generate-series

I have a query to generate a report based on a date series that is grouped by `date` and `employee_id`. The date should be based on a particular time zone, in this case 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'. But this can change depending on where the user's time zone is.

```
SELECT 
     d::date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' AS created_date,  
     e.id,  
     e.name,
     e.division_id,
     ARRAY_AGG(
       a.id
     ) as rows,        
     MIN(a.created_at) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 1) as min_time_in,
     MAX(a.created_at) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 2) as max_time_out,
     ARRAY_AGG(
       CASE
           WHEN a.activity_type = 1
           THEN a.created_at
           ELSE NULL
       END
     ) as check_ins,
     ARRAY_AGG(
       CASE
           WHEN a.activity_type = 2
           THEN a.created_at
           ELSE NULL
       END
     ) as check_outs        
FROM    (SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) FROM attendance) AS r(startdate,enddate)
  , generate_series(
        startdate::timestamp, 
        enddate::timestamp, 
        interval '1 day') g(d)
    CROSS JOIN  employee e
    LEFT JOIN   attendance a ON a.created_at::date = d::date AND e.id = a.employee_id
    where d::date = date '2020-11-20' and division_id = 1
GROUP BY 
    created_date
  , e.id
  , e.name
  , e.division_id
ORDER BY 
    created_date
  , e.id;
```

Definition and sample data for table `attendance`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE attendance (
    id int,
    employee_id int,
    activity_type int,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO attendance VALUES
( 1, 1, 1,'2020-11-18 07:10:25 +00:00'),
( 2, 2, 1,'2020-11-18 07:30:25 +00:00'),
( 3, 3, 1,'2020-11-18 07:50:25 +00:00'),
( 4, 2, 2,'2020-11-18 19:10:25 +00:00'),
( 5, 3, 2,'2020-11-18 19:22:38 +00:00'),
( 6, 1, 2,'2020-11-18 20:01:05 +00:00'),
( 7, 1, 1,'2020-11-19 07:11:23 +00:00'),
( 8, 1, 2,'2020-11-19 16:21:53 +00:00'), <-- Asia/Kuala_Lumpur +8 should be in 20.11 (refer to the check_outs field in the results output)
( 9, 1, 1,'2020-11-19 19:11:23 +00:00'), <-- Asia/Kuala_Lumpur +8 should be in 20.11 (refer to the check_ins field in the results output)
(10, 1, 2,'2020-11-19 20:21:53 +00:00'), <-- Asia/Kuala_Lumpur +8 should be in 20.11 (refer to the check_outs field in the results output)
(11, 1, 1,'2020-11-20 07:41:38 +00:00'),
(12, 1, 2,'2020-11-20 08:52:01 +00:00');
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0ffe56a820989467da6055484cfad85f) to test.

The query does not include rows 8-10 in the output for the time zone Asia/Kuala_Lumpur +8, though it should. Result shows "rows" field `11,12`.

How can I fix the query so that it generates the report based on dates of a given time zone? (Meaning I can change `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur` to `America/New_York` etc.)

I was told to do something like this:

```sql
where created_at >= timestamp '2020-11-20' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
and   created_at <  timestamp '2020-11-20' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' + interval '1 day'
```

But I am not sure how to apply it. Does not seem to work properly in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=716c719de4c98cfb0598f83d85e37137). It should include rows 8,9,10,11,12 but only rows 8,9,10 show up.

Comment: What are the column types for the `startdate` and `endate` values; timestamp, timestamptz, something else? What is the server `TimeZone set to? So timestamps are being entered at 'UTC`, correct? Have you tried something like; `startdate::timestamp AT TIME ZONE ' Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' , enddate::timestamp AT TIME ZONE ' Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'`?

Comment: I'ved updated to try in startdate and enddate https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=716c719de4c98cfb0598f83d85e37137. created_at timestamp with time zone <-- thats how its defined. the server timezone is "GB", my own server is different timezone. I'd like the query to output according to the desired timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### DB design

Consider some modifications to your setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id           int PRIMARY KEY  -- !
, name         text             -- do NOT use char(n) !
, division_id  int
);

CREATE  TABLE attendance (
  id             int PRIMARY KEY  --!
, employee_id    int NOT NULL REFERENCES employee -- FK!
, activity_type  int
, created_at     timestamptz NOT NULL
);
```

Defining a PK makes it easier to aggregate rows, because the PK covers the whole row in the `GROUP BY` clause. See:

- [Why can't I exclude dependent columns from `GROUP BY` when I aggregate by a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095987/why-cant-i-exclude-dependent-columns-from-group-by-when-i-aggregate-by-a-key/62096322#62096322)

I wouldn't use "name" as column name. It's not descriptive. Every other column could be named "name". Consider:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)
- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

#### Query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (        -- complete employee/date grid for division in range
   SELECT g.d::date AS the_date, id AS employee_id, name, division_id
   FROM  (
      SELECT generate_series(MIN(created_at) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
                           , MAX(created_at) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
                           , interval '1 day')
      FROM   attendance
      ) g(d)
   CROSS  JOIN employee e
   WHERE  e.division_id = 1
   ) de
LEFT   JOIN (  -- checkins & checkouts per employee/date for division in range
   SELECT employee_id, ts::date AS the_date
        , array_agg(id) as rows
        , min(ts)             FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 1) AS min_check_in
        , max(ts)             FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 2) AS max_check_out
        , array_agg(ts::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 1) AS check_ins
        , array_agg(ts::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 2) AS check_outs
   FROM  (
      SELECT a.id, a.employee_id, a.activity_type, a.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' AS ts  -- convert to timestamp
      FROM   employee   e
      JOIN   attendance a ON a.employee_id = e.id
   -- WHERE  a.created_at >= timestamp '2020-11-20' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' -- "sargable" expressions
   -- AND    a.created_at <  timestamp '2020-11-21' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' -- exclusive upper bound (includes all of 2020-11-20);
      AND    e.division_id = 1
      ORDER  BY a.employee_id, a.created_at, a.activity_type  -- optional to guarantee sorted arrays
   ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) a USING (the_date, employee_id)
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c199f944fd7cc5f51c7fac3d32996ef8)*

Note that my query outputs local date and time for Asia/Kuala_Lumpur:

```
test=> SELECT timestamptz '2020-11-20 08:52:01 +0' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' AS local_ts;
      local_ts       
---------------------
 2020-11-20 16:52:01
```

Where to start? You **need** to understand the concepts of time zones and the Postgres data types `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) vs. `timestamp without time zone` (`timestamp`). Else, it will be confusion without end. Start here:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Most notably, `timestamptz` does *not* store a time zone:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-data-type-timestamp-with-time-zone/28876266#28876266)

When simply casting `timestamptz` to `date` or `timestamp`, the current time zone setting of the session is assumed. ***Not*** what you want. Provide a time zone explicitly with the `AT TIME ZONE` construct to avoid this pifall. In your fiddle you have both:

```sql
  ...
  , generate_series(
        startdate::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', 
        enddate::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', 
        interval '1 day') g(d)
   ...
```

Also ***not*** doing what you want. After the (faulty!) cast to `timestamp`, the `AT TIME ZONE` construct translates the values back to `timestamptz`.

Also, your query generates the complete Cartesian Product of all users and and the maximum range of days in the the table `attendance`, only to reduce it back to a single day with:

```sql
    where created_at >= timestamp '2020-11-20' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
    and   created_at <  timestamp '2020-11-20' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' + interval '1 day'
```

The `WHERE` clause finally does what it's supposed to do. But it makes no sense to first generate the full range of days, only to throw away most of it. (Seems you copied that from [my other fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100333/postgres-sql-convert-to-orm-queryset-for-a-date-generate-series-with-cross-joi#comment115469872_65100333) in the meantime?)

I commented out the `WHERE` clause and kept an optimized version of your `generate_series()` in my query as proof of concept. Further reading:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Comment: thanks for the quite elaborate explanation. I cant fundamentally change the DB design (to timestamptz), so I would have to stick to the original definitions. Back to the query, I can get my intended output for 19-20.11.2020 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=96719b3bccfbd4a1b63ab9e38e9821c5. but I still find it weird on the generate_series using dates outside the range 2020-11-20 and 2020-11-21. is this correct ? something looks not right.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=60166a27d821b7f58d2cdc02addfa33c this is another I tried -10 UTC with Pacific/Honolulu. 19.11.2020 does not appear

Comment: What do you mean  "change to `timestamptz`"? `changed_at` *is* `timestamptz`, I didn't change that. Also, my `generate_series()` does not use `date` but `timestamp`. Your `generate_series()` in both new fiddles, however, uses `timestamptz`, which makes no sense. The subquery `a` which we join to outputs `timestamp`, not `timestamptz`. Neither does `MIN` or `MAX` make any sense in there.

Comment: Are you aware that `AT TIME ZONE` converts `timestamp` to `timestamptz` and vice versa? Did you read up on the topic like I suggested? You'll have to, or confusion will never end.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c199f944fd7cc5f51c7fac3d32996ef8 <-- i belive this your db<>fiddle (created_at timestamptz NOT NULL). I cant make that modification as it is live. Can you use the existing db design instead ?

Comment: `timestamptz` is a synonym of `timestamp with time zone`. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226018/discussion-between-axil-and-erwin-brandstetter).